# How to calculate $\frac{\partial V}{\partial V_n}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

I can't find how I can calculate this simple partial derivative:

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial V_n}$$

Where $V$ - vector, and $V_n$ - n-element of the $V$ vector.

How can I calculate this derivative?

Comment: Have you ever seen the kronecker delta? $\delta_{ab}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably doing this as an example would be better.

If $V = V(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)$ is a function of $n$ variables, then $\partial V/\partial v_k$ is a derivative of $V$ with respect to $v_k$ and all other $v_i$'s held constant.

For example, let $$V(v_1, v_2) = 3v_1 + \sin(v_2) + e^{v_1 v_2}$$ then
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial v_1} = 3 + v_2 e^{v_1 v_2}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\frac{\partial V}{\partial v_2} = \cos(v_2) + v_1 e^{v_1 v_2}
$$

In a similar way, if 
$$W(w_1, w_2) = \left(3w_1, \sin(w_2), e^{w_1 w_2}\right)$$ then
$$
\frac{\partial W}{\partial w_1} = \left(3, 0, v_2 e^{v_1 v_2}\right)
\quad \text{and} \quad
\frac{\partial W}{\partial w_2} = \left(0, \cos(v_2), v_1 e^{v_1 v_2}\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As I understand you just differentiate a vector-function? Is it the same as I want? I meant that I have vector with M elements, and I want to find partial derivative for n-element of this vector. Or maybe I understand something wrong?

Comment: @don-prog yes, added that example explicitiy

Comment: Now it looks more clear to me, thanks. But can you explain what is the last element in this vector(I mean $e^{w_1 w_2}$, on the left side you have $W(W_1, W_2)$ but on the right side you have 3 elements)? And why instead of direct using of elements you **can** multiply element by a factor($3W_1$) or use it as argument($\sin(W_2)$)? I think I missed something.

Comment: @don-prog The notation $W = W(w_1,w_2)$ means that $W$ depends on $w_1$ and $w_2$, in other words, that $W$ is a function of 2 variables. That has no relationship to how many *components* will be in the elements of the range of $W$. Here, $W:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, the dimensions of domain and range *do not* have to be the same.

Comment: Understood. And for our mutual understanding, if we have vector, where dimensions of domain = range, and where each argument used directly(I mean simple vector $V=(v_1, ..., v_K)$), e.g. if we have  $V=(v_1, v_2, v_3)$, then $\frac{\partial V}{\partial v_2} = (0, 1, 0)$, is it right? In other words, Paul's answer is correct too?

Comment: @don-prog yes, that is correct -- PaulAljabar's answer is a special case of mine

Comment: I marked this answer as accepted, because it's the most clear and broad. Thanks!

Comment: @don-prog thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the derivative of a vector $\mathbf{v} = (v_1, \ldots, v_K)^T$ with respect to its $n^{th}$ component $v_n$, and assuming that the different components are independent of each other ....

... then the partial derivative $\partial \mathbf{v} / \partial v_n$ will be a vector with all zeros except for a 1 in the $n^{th}$ position.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I thought. Is there an easy way to write this in the equation?